# vue,js vue-router 2 component data doesn't update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource, vue-router

I'm fairly new to vue.js and trying to build an SPA. Basicly i define all routes from my backend with an alias to my API endpoints. a lot of them using the same component. Data gets fetched with router.beforeEach and vue-resource.

Now when i navigate from a route to another route which share the same template, my router-view doens't get updated.

Here's my code:

```
 <script>

var data = {
    content: null
}

const site = {
    template:'<div>{{this.title}}</div>',
    data: function () {
      return data.content.body
    }
}

const home = {
    template:'<div>{{this.title}}</div>',
    data: function () {
      return data.content.body
    }
}

const routes = [
            { path: '/api/12.json', component: home, alias: '/' },
            { path: '/api/4.json', component: site, alias: '/projekte' },
            { path: '/api/5.json', component: site, alias: '/projekte/projekt-1' },
            { path: '/api/7.json', component: site, alias: '/projekte/projekt-2' },
            { path: '/api/6.json', component: site, alias: '/projekte/projekt-3' },
            { path: '/api/8.json', component: site, alias: '/agentur' },
            { path: '/api/9.json', component: site, alias: '/lab' },
            { path: '/api/10.json', component: site, alias: '/kontakt' },
        ]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    Vue.http.get(to.matched[0].path).then((response) => {

        data.content = response;
        console.log(data.content);
        next();

    }, (response) => {

        data.content = {
            'body': {
                'title': 'Error 404'
            }
        };
        next();

    });
})

const app = new Vue({
    router

}).$mount('#app')

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` object is not part of your Vue component. It is defined outside of your Vue app.

Even though your components - `home` and `site` returns the `data.content.body` object, your main `data` object is not part of Vue's reactivity system. Therefore, the changes in that `data` object are not tracked.

You can read more about it here: https://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html

To ensure that this does not happen, you need to define your `data` as part of your component itself. And you need to do your http calls as part of `mounted` hook on the route component, which has access to `this.data` of the component.

If you need to share `data` between components (most likely), then you need to use state management using **vuex** that allows you to have a shared state for the entire Vue app.

You can read more about Vuex here: http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

Comment: The documentation of vue-router shows that the global navigation guard can be definded outside [link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: Yes, you can do it. But it is recommended to contain your code within the app. This will allow your team members to understand better, and you can allocate ownership of each component to a different person, so things are under control. It is more of a practical benefit than technical.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of vue / vue-router / vuex / vue-resource example for API Calls. Thanks at [Mani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654825/mani) for the hint i needed.

```
const site = {
    template:'<div>{{ content.title }}</div>',
    computed: {
        content (){
            return store.state.routeContent
        }
    }
}

const home = {
    template:'<div>{{ content.title }}</div>',
    computed: {
        content (){
            return store.state.routeContent
        }
    }
}

const notFound = {
    template: '<div>{{ content.title }}</div>',
    computed: {
        content (){
            return store.state.routeContent
        }
    }
}

const routes = [
    { path: '/api/12.json', component: home, alias: '/' },
    { path: '/api/4.json', component: site, alias: '/projekte' },
    { path: '/api/5.json', component: site, alias: '/projekte/projekt-1' },
    { path: '/api/7.json', component: site, alias: '/projekte/projekt-2' },
    { path: '/api/6.json', component: site, alias: '/projekte/projekt-3' },
    { path: '/api/8.json', component: site, alias: '/agentur' },
    { path: '/api/9.json', component: site, alias: '/lab' },
    { path: '/api/10.json', component: site, alias: '/kontakt' },
    { path: '/*', component: notFound }
]

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        routeContent: null
    },
    mutations: {
        routeContent (state, payload) {
            state.routeContent = payload
            document.title = payload.title
        }
    }
})

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    Vue.http.get(to.matched[0].path).then((response) => {
        store.commit('routeContent', response.body)
        next()

    }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        errorObject = {
            'title': 'Error 404'
        },
        store.commit('routeContent', errorObject)
        next()

    });
})

const app = new Vue({
    router

}).$mount('#app')
```